# Tomee Embedded Adapter + Arquillian + Jax-RS - Test Jaas

Tags: java, jax-rs, integration-testing, jaas, jboss-arquillian

I am currently having trouble testing Restful methods/paths that are secured using `@RolesAllowed`, these roles are pulled from the database when the user logs in through a custom JAAS LoginModule (I am able to tests those rest methods/paths that don't require any role.)

I have been stocked on this for a few days now, and have looked everywhere (specially here in SO) for answers that had lead me to where I'm now, which I will describe ahead).

I believe I will be able to log in users if I get my custom LoginModule to run on the TomEE Embedded Adapter (which is currently not).

My question is the following:

How can I set the option `-Djava.security.auth.login.config=path/to/login.config"` in the TomEE Embedded Adapter, in order for my custom LoginModule to be used as the JAASRealm?

I have done the following:

1. Added to Arquillian.xml (SO is omitting `<property>` tags for some reason.)

   ```
    <property name="catalina_opts">
     Djava.security.auth.login.config=$CATALINA_HOME/conf/jaas.config" 
    </property>
   ```
2. Added to `pom.xml` in the surefire plugin:  (SO is omitting `<argline>` tags for some reason.)

   ```
    <argLine>
        -Djava.security.auth.login.config=${project.basedir}/target/test-classes/conf/test-login.config"
    </argLine>
   ```
3. Added the realm in the test-server.xml and added the property in arquillian.xml

in `test-server.xml`

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm"
     appName="CustomJAASModule"
     userClassName="com.myapp.UserPrincipal, com.myapp.PasswordPrincipal"
     roleClassNames="com.myapp.RolePrincipal">
</Realm>
```

in `arquillian.xml`

```
<property name="serverXml">test-server.xml</property>
```

4. Replaced context.xml with `test-context.xml` when creating the WebArchive through ShrinkWrap in the test

   ```
    @Deployment    
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
            .addPackages(true, Appointment.class.getPackage(), AppointmentsFacadeREST.class
            .getPackage(), ClassConstraints.class.getPackage())
            .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
            .addAsResource("users.properties")
            .addAsResource("groups.properties");

        war.delete("WEB-INF/web.xml");
        war.delete("WEB-INF/context.xml");
        war.addAsWebInfResource("test-web.xml", "web.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource("test-context.xml", "context.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");

        return war;
    }
   ```

(I'm unable to format the above code for some reason, although there are 4 leading spaces in each line)

Everything runs smoothly in the regular server, I am able to debug the `LoginModule` and set breakpoints which work perfectly fine, the problem is just in the embedded.

I am using the following frameworks/technologies:

TomEE+ 1.7.2 (Jax-RS, OpenEJB, etc.)
JPA - OpenJPA/MySQL

Running on Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: You can use eight spaces to format code inside of markdown lists. Add four spaces to following paragraphs that are "line-skipped".  The will keep the indentation for multiple paragraph list parts (that includes code blocks in between those parts).

Comment: Thank you @peeskillet, I edit the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying to get something like this working as well and have finally succeeded today. As for your question, you can actually put the realm configuration in your context.xml. Furthermore,the JAAS realm also allows you setting the path to the configuration file. So, you have:

In test-context.xml, either add the following lines or replace it altogether:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm"
    appName="CustomJAASModule"
    configFile="login.config"
    userClassName="com.myapp.UserPrincipal, com.myapp.PasswordPrincipal"
    roleClassNames="com.myapp.RolePrincipal">
</Realm>
```

In your test class (I took the liberty of replacing some of your code with convenience methods):

```
@Deployment    
public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
    WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
        .addPackages(true, Appointment.class.getPackage(), AppointmentsFacadeREST.class
        .getPackage(), ClassConstraints.class.getPackage())
        .setWebXML("test-web.xml")
        .addAsManifestResource("test-context.xml", "context.xml")
        .addAsManifestResource("test-persistence.xml", "persistence.xml")
        .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
        .addAsResource("test-login.config", "login.config")
        .addAsResource("users.properties")
        .addAsResource("groups.properties");
    return war;
}
```

It seems you cannot use server.xml since the classes required for the JAAS authentication need to be in ../arquillian-apache-tomee/lib/ and there is no way to add classes to that path at this time. This approach works because web.xml, context.xml and persistence.xml will take precedence over their counterparts in the container configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer EJJ, unfortunately I gave up on this long ago and eventually switched to WildFly. There's no way I can test whether your approach works. But given that it worked for you I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm"
appName="CustomJAASModule"
configFile="login.config"
userClassName="com.myapp.UserPrincipal, com.myapp.PasswordPrincipal"
roleClassNames="com.myapp.RolePrincipal">
</Realm>
```

Results in: jar:file:/C:/Users/piotr/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomee/openejb-core/7.0.2/openejb-core-7.0.2.jar!/login.config which is wrong.

You need to choose different/unique name for your file, for example:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm" 
configFile="test-login.config" 
appName="FakeLoginModule"
userClassNames="org.jboss.security.SimplePrincipal"
roleClassNames="org.jboss.security.SimpleGroup" />
```

and

```
.addAsManifestResource("test-context.xml", "context.xml")
.addAsResource("test-login.config", "test-login.config")
```